# How to compile a multiple python files into an android app

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, google-play, apk

I understand that its relatively simple to compile a single .py program into an APK (using something like buildoser) and put it onto the Google Play Store, however my python project is split into many files, inside various folders of one directory. Can I compile all these into a single android program for the Play Store? Or do I have to merge everything to run in a single program?